# Class extension typealias's property type constraint

Tags: swift, type-constraints, type-alias, type-extension

Mission: I need to provide an Array extension method which would compare 2 arrays of raw representables whose raw type conforms to Equatable and say if the arrays contain the same elements by reusing the below pieces of code.

What I have at the moment:

```
public extension Array {
  func containsTheSameElements(as array: [Element], condition: @escaping (Element, Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    var localCopy = array

    let countOfUncommonElements = reduce(0) { (uncommonElementsCount: Int, item: Element) -> Int in
      if let index = localCopy.index(where: {condition(item, $0)}) {
        localCopy.remove(at: index)
        return uncommonElementsCount
      } else {
        return uncommonElementsCount + 1
      }
    }

    return countOfUncommonElements == 0 && count == array.count
  }
}

func enumComparisonClosure<T: RawRepresentable>(firstItem: T, secondItem: T) -> Bool where T.RawValue: Equatable {
  return firstItem == secondItem
}
```

How I'm using it at the moment:

```
class Somewhere {
  enum EnumType: String {
    case first
    case second
  }

  func method() {
    let firstArray: [EnumType] = [.first, .second]
    let secondArray: [EnumType] = [.second]

    firstArray.containsTheSameElements(as: secondArray, condition: enumComparisonClosure)
  }
}
```

How I would like to use it:

```
firstArray.containsTheSameElements(as: secondArray)
```

How I would like to be able to implement it:

```
public extension Array {
  func containsTheSameElements<Element: RawRepresentable>(as array: [Element]) -> Bool where Element.RawValue: Equatable {
    return containsTheSameElements(as: array, condition: enumComparisonClosure)
  }
}
```

How can I constrain the Array's extension "Element" typealias to be a RawRepresentable with RawValue of Equatable type?

Or what would be another approach to make this comparison possible?

Comment: Using `filter` only to end up getting its `count` isn't recommended. Try using reduce, to increment a count, instead.

Comment: @Alexander I guess you are right. It's just that for me it was easier to imagine as "filtering" one array of elements which are present in the other and then see how many are still left in the first one.

Comment: `array.filter{ $0.someCondition }` => `array.reduce(0) { $0.someCondition ? $0 + 1 : $0 }`. It's a bit longer, but its faster and clearer intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraints on the extension are separated by a comma, not
by `&`. The `containsTheSameElements` must take a `[T]` argument
where `T` is a `RawRepresentable` with the same `RawValue`
as the array elements.

Example:

```
extension Array where Element: RawRepresentable, Element.RawValue: Equatable {

    func containsTheSameElements<T>(as array: [T]) -> Bool
    where T: RawRepresentable, T.RawValue == Element.RawValue
    {
        return self.count == array.count &&
            !zip(self, array).contains { $0.rawValue != $1.rawValue }
    }
}
```

**Update:** It is simpler if you need it only for arrays
of the same type:

```
extension Array where Element: RawRepresentable, Element.RawValue: Equatable {

    func containsTheSameElements(as array: [Element]) -> Bool
    {
        return self.count == array.count &&
            !zip(self, array).contains { $0.rawValue != $1.rawValue }
    }
}
```

or, reusing your existing method:

```
extension Array where Element: RawRepresentable, Element.RawValue: Equatable {

    func containsTheSameElements(as array: [Element]) -> Bool
    {
        return containsTheSameElements(as: array, condition: enumComparisonClosure)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to reuse the existing containsTheSameElements function?

Comment: @Fawkes: Do you need the method for arrays of the same  type, or for arrays of (possibly) different type with same RawValue?

Comment: I would like to apply it to arrays with the same type. [but whose type is raw representable and their rawvalue can be compared]

Comment: @Fawkes: In that case your initial version was already very close to the solution, see update.

Comment: Perfect! I still don't understand why Swift was complaining =/

Comment: @Fawkes: it was the `&` instead of a comma. But actually you can  simply compare `if  firstArray == secondArray` in that case!

Comment: Look at my modified solution. If I try it like that, swift does not allow me to pass that array as a parameter...

Comment: Unfortunately just "==" will probably work if they are in the same order.

Comment: @Fawkes: Your comparison method would consider `[.a, .a, .b]` and `[.a, .b, .b]` as equal, is that intended?

Comment: not intended :) I guess I should remove all the elements I find as common before next iteration